# How to use my own class inside a Vue file

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm making a webpage using Nuxt and I would like to make a class and use it in one of my .vue files. I've tried using an import: `import Card from "~/assets/mylib/Card.js"` but that doesn't work. Not sure how to access my Card.js file inside of a .vue file.

**index.vue**

```
import Card from "~/assets/mylib/Card.js"
created() {
  let card = new Card("blue")
}
```

**Card.js**

```
class Card {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color
  }
}
```

**error:**

```
_assets_mylib_Card_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a is not a constructor
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? explain *doesn't work*.

Comment: I added more information.

Comment: need to export it `export default class Card {`

Comment: That was it! Thank you :)

Comment: if you epxorting it as default you dont need to name your export, so you can write it like this `export default class {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify **Card.js** as follows:

```
export default class Card {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color
  }
}
```

Then import it from within **index.vue** as follows:

```
import { Card } from "~/assets/mylib/Card"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your **Card.js** like beow

```
export class Card {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color
  }
}
```

and import in vue file like below

```
import { Card } from "~/assets/mylib/Card"
```